# Is it correct for using concatenation operation in verilog instantiation

Tags: verilog

Is this correct for using concatenation operation in verilog module instantiation?

```
hall1 A2(
         .DIR(DIR2),
         .PWM(PWM2),
         .Hall({FH31B,FH21B,FH11B}),
         .Top_drive({GTOPC1B,GTOPB1B,GTOPA1B}),
         .Bot_drive({GBOTC1B,GBOTB1B,GBOTA1B})
        );
```

Here `Hall` is an array of 3-bit wire,`Top_drive` and `Bot_drive` are an array of 3-bit reg variable.

Comment: While it is correct, it doesn't help the readability of your code. I prefer to concatenate to a local variable `Top_drive` and use this variable in the module instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct, you can use concatenation in port's connection.